# Using Hibernate setFirstResult without any ordering

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate. I am confused with criteria's `setFirstResult` method. 
From the documentation it seems hibernate returns rows from the the given number.

Since SQL query does not guarantee the ordering of rows without order by clause, 
how `setFirstQuery` works in this case(without orderBy clause)? 
Does hibernate read index information from the database?

If I execute same SQL query multiple times, ordering might change, in this case how `setFirstResult` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate can not do something by its own unless its supported by underlying databases. Because Hibernate queries finally get transformed to `Sql` only.

Having said that it uses underlying databases capabilities like for PostgresSQL and MySQL it will generate query like `limit ? offset ?` .

You can add custom order using `addOrder`

```
.addOrder( Order.asc("name") )
```

Comment: The part about "by default it will be Order By on Primary key" here is inaccurate.  Hibernate does not add implicit ordering and the order of the returned results is completely up to the underlying database.

Comment: I know about PostgreSQL and MySQL that it uses Limit and offset but in absence of these ie. Oracle database what does it uses?

Answer (score 0):

It is your task to add an order by, the function as you noticed won't guarantee same results if executed several times over the same set of data.
`setFirstResult` is typically used in pagination.